# MyBatis PersistenceException SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms

Tags: spring, connection, mybatis, mapper, sql-sessions

I'm getting a PersistenceException when the connection is opened and the query is run (inside RentalServiceImpl try{}catch{} method the the mapper is run).

It's the first time I try to use sqlSessionFactory.openSession() of MyBatis so I'm not sure if my use is right or it's a problem of connection. Is there even a way to check if the SqlSession is correctly open?

Could you help me?

```
24-10-2022 19:31:58.431 [ERROR] - [https-jsse-nio-27100-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/app/GY7/1/fmps/v1/rental] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
### The error may exist in com/gy7/rental/jdbc/mapper/TestAutomationMapper (best guess)
### The error may involve com.gy7.rental.jdbc.mapper.TestAutomationMapper.selectAllTestDataItem
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.readFromSocket(SSLSocketChannel.java:560)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrapHandshakeMessage(SSLSocketChannel.java:479)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.doSSLHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:436)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:126)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:308)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOConnectPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOConnectPacket.java:235)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:114)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1481)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:540)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:224)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:219)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.getConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.popConnection(PooledDataSource.java:432)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.getConnection(PooledDataSource.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:139)
    at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:337)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.prepareStatement(ReuseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.selectAllTestDataItem(Unknown Source)
    at com.gy7.rental.service.rentalServiceImpl.findAllTestDataItems(RentalServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.gy7.rental.controller.RentalController.searchMessage(RentalController.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

TaDataSourceConfiguration.java :

```
public class TaDataSourceConfiguration {
    
    public static SqlSessionFactory buildSqlSessionFactory() {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String user = prop.getProperty("DB_USER_TA");
        String url = prop.getProperty("DB_TA_URL");
        String driver = prop.getProperty("DB_TA_DRIVER");

        DataSource dataSource = new PooledDataSource(driver, url, user, "mypassword");//TODO HIDE PW
        Environment environment = new Environment("Development", new JdbcTransactionFactory(), dataSource);
        Configuration configuration = new org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration(environment);
        configuration.addMapper(TestAutomationMapper.class);

        SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
        return builder.build(configuration);

}
```

RentalServiceImpl.java :

```
public List<TestDataItemEntity> findAllTestDataItems() {

    List<TestDataItemEntity> testDataItemEntityList = null;

    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = TaDataSourceConfiguration.buildSqlSessionFactory();


    SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {

        TestAutomationMapper taMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(TestAutomationMapper.class);
        testDataItemEntityList = taMapper.selectAllTestDataItem();//Line 32 where it goes in Exception !
        sqlSession.commit();
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }

    return testDataItemEntityList;
}
```

Application.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.gy7.rental.jdbc.mapper")
@MappedTypes({TestDataItemEntity.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication application =
            new SpringApplication(Application.class);

    application.setAddCommandLineProperties(false);
    application.run(args);
    }
}
```

TestAutomationMapper.java :

```
@Mapper
public interface TestAutomationMapper {

    @Results(id = "allTestCase", value = {
            @Result(property = "carNr", column = "CAR_NR"),
            @Result(property = "carDesc", column = "CAR_DESC"),
            @Result(property = "region", column = "REGION"),
    })
    @ResultType(TestDataItemEntity.class)
    @Select("SELECT *  FROM   TEST_DATA_ITEM tdi")
    List<TestDataItemEntity> selectAllTestDataItem();

}
```

TestDataItemEntity.java

```
    public class TestDataItemEntity {

    private Integer carNr;
    private String carDesc;
    private String region;

    //getter & setter ...
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Config-local.properties :

```
DB_TA_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=xxxxxxxx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxxxxxxxxx)))
DB_USER_TA=technical_user
DB_DRIVER_TA=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Please include the 'full' stack trace.

Comment: I dont have the fulls tackTrace because the app use some external and private library which intercept the exception.
I found the first error, it isn't able to read the values from  Config-local.properties..(all String were null).
Now I've copy pasted the connection url, user and driver values directly in the java file and I get "PersistenceException IO Error: Connection closed" (post updated)

Comment: Nevermind Now I've found and added the whole stacktrace

Comment: this is the line that throw exception according to the stacktrace:
 testDataItemEntityList = taMapper.selectAllTestDataItem();

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you are not supposed to create `SqlSessionFactory` in your code. Please read the docs for [mybatis-spring-boot](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/) and [mybatis-spring](https://mybatis.org/spring/). If you are new to MyBatis + Spring Boot, I would recommend using a working skeleton project like [this one](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Ave for the reply, in the end I refavtored the code using spring annotation of @configuration class as suggested in your link  "mybatis-spring-boot". It took a while but now it works

Comment: It's not easy to untangle Spring configurations once it gets messed up. Anyway, I'm glad to know that you have made it work. :)